# How to integrate sorting and pagination in angular2 rc5?

Tags: sorting, angular, pagination

I am trying it integrate sorting and pagination in angular2 rc5. Pagination is working with ng2-pagination, searching for sorting. Any good example for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still looking for answer (only for pagination), This link is a useful resource -

[Implementing Pagination in angular2 > v.RC5](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination)

I integrated it within 5 minutes after I got above link.

In case - link is no longer available , here are the steps

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination'; // <-- import the module
imort {MyComponent} from './my.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, Ng2PaginationModule], // <-- include it in your app module
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    bootstrap: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }"> ... </li>
    </ul>

    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
    `
})
export class MyComponent {
    public collection: any[] = someArrayOfThings;  
}
```

Therefor, For server side paging we can change this line of `pagination-controls` with replace some custom event -

This event (`myCustomEvent($event)`) must be defined and declared in component class or whatever you are going to use as a bootstrapper.

For sorting, excuse me for now.